# Using Tor, why am I getting an error message that says, "Firefox cannot find the server for..."?

Tags: firefox, server

Haven't used Tor in awhile. While searching first topically, I was timing out; then I got an error saying that Firefox was unable to find the (or connect to) the server for ... I finally tried Amazon, still no results. The search bar indicates something about Google and Disconnect.me; in the past, I thought that Tor was its own browser and from what I can see, Disconnect me is a VPN, of which I have one already. (I've turned it on and then off while trying to search.)

I don't understand what is happening and if something can be changed; would appreciate suggestions, guidance.

Comment: [Disconnect.me](https://search.disconnect.me/) is also a search provider with privacy in mind! and it is the [New Search Provider](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-45-released#Search) in TBB.

Comment: *by the way:* "Tor was its own browser"... the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html) was always and is a [modified version of Firefox ESR](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/)!

Comment: Thank you for the information. So, the reason I could not access anything had zero to do with the browser or the search engine. It is helpful to rule that out.

Comment: Can you provide some information how you configured your browser or do you use Tor Browser (which version)?